# Table width problem in outlook

Tags: html, outlook, outlook-2007, html-table

I need to display a table with 14 columns in the outlook mail. The column heading are some extra length and i need to show the headings in a signle line. so I am setting width for every column, but the problem is the whole table is not widening after some width. example if I give extra width it is working fine. if i give extra width to all the columns then all the columns are adjusting and all the column headings are coming in 2 or 3 lines.

I copied the source from the outlook mail and I saved the same mail and I opened with IE browser then it is working fine. I am getting problem only when with outlook client.

Can someone help me in this regards

Thanks in advance
Satish

Answer (score 1):

using "min-width" property. your problem may be solved try it....